# Get the value of a variant, which itself could be another variant

Tags: c++, c++17, template-meta-programming, variant, algebraic-data-types

I have a variant `ScalarVar`

```
using ScalarVar = std::variant<int, std::string>;
```

And a variant `Var`, which could itself be a `ScalarVar` or a `std::vector` of `ScalarVar`s

```
using Var = std::variant<ScalarVar, std::vector<ScalarVar>>;
```

I want to make a function `template<typename T, typename Variant> T Get(const Variant& var);` that when given a variant that does not include inner variants will act just like `std::get<T>`, i.e it will return the value of `T` if `Variant` currently contains a `T`, or if given a variant that contains other variants, it will recursively get the contained type until a non variant is found, and then return that.

Here is my best attempt at this so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <string>
#include <typeindex>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

template<typename T, typename... T2>
struct is_variant { static inline constexpr bool value = false; };

template<typename... T>
struct is_variant<std::variant<T...>> { static inline constexpr bool value = true; };

template<typename T, typename Variant>
T Get(const Variant& var) {
    static_assert (is_variant<Variant>::value == true, "Template parameter Variant must be a std::variant");
    auto inner = std::visit([](const auto& i){ return i; }, var);
    if constexpr(is_variant<typeof(inner)>::value) {
        return Get<T>(inner);
    }
    else return inner;
}

int main()
{
    using ScalarVar = std::variant<int, std::string>;
    using Var = std::variant<ScalarVar, std::vector<ScalarVar>>;

    ScalarVar s = 5;
    std::cout << Get<int>(s) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This should simply return a `T` if `T` is not an `std::variant`, and return `std::get<InnerT>` if `T` is an std::variant that contains type `T`.

But I get a very complex compilation error from gcc for the line:

`std::cout << Get<int>(s) << std::endl`

```
/usr/include/c++/9/variant:1005: error: invalid conversion from ‘std::__success_type<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::type (*)(Get(const Variant&) [with T = int; Variant = std::variant<int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >]::<lambda(const auto:22&)>&&, const std::variant<int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >&)’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> (*)(Get(const Variant&) [with T = int; Variant = std::variant<int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >]::<lambda(const auto:22&)>&&, const std::variant<int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >&)’} to ‘int (*)(Get(const Variant&) [with T = int; Variant = std::variant<int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >]::<lambda(const auto:22&)>&&, const std::variant<int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >&)’ [-fpermissive]
 1005 |       { return _Array_type{&__visit_invoke}; }
      |                                           ^
      |                                           |
      |                                           std::__success_type<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::type (*)(Get(const Variant&) [with T = int; Variant = std::variant<int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >]::<lambda(const auto:22&)>&&, const std::variant<int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >&) {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> (*)(Get(const Variant&) [with T = int; Variant = std::variant<int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >]::<lambda(const auto:22&)>&&, const std::variant<int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >&)}
```

How can I get my required behaviour?

Comment: It's not clear where from in your code does that error originate.

Comment: Okay, I will edit the question

Comment: What is `typeof`?

Comment: @Timo A GCC extension equivalent to `decltype`, IIRC.

Comment: Say you have two scalars `ScalarVar i = 0; ScalarVar j = 1;` and a vector `std::vector<ScalarVar> vec{i, j}`. What should `Get<int>(vec)` return? The first matching value, e.g., `0`?

Comment: @pschill `vec` is not a `std::variant`, so a compiler error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
std::visit([](const auto& i){ return i; }, var);
```

Calling this directly from `main` with `ScalarVar var = 5;` produces a similar message.

Let's see what [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) says about the return type of `std::visit` (C++17):

> The return type is deduced from the returned expression as if by
>   decltype. The call is ill-formed if the invocation above is not a
>   valid expression of the same type and value category, for all
>   combinations of alternative types of all variants.

This means that you can not call `std::visit` as above, because it had to return different types (`int` / `std::string`) depending on the value inside.

You can use function overloading and use two distinct functions for `std::variant` and other types:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
T Get(U const& value)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, U>)
    {
        return value;
    }
    // If you get here, none of the nested variants had a value of type T.
    return T();
}

template <typename T, typename... Args>
T Get(std::variant<Args...> const& var)
{
    return std::visit(
        [](auto const& value) { return Get<T>(value); },
        var
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to distinguish between `T`, `std::variant<...>` and everything else when you call `std::visit`.

```
template<typename T>
struct Getter {
    T operator()(const T & t) { return t; }

    template <typename ... Ts>
    T operator()(const std::variant<Ts...> & var) { return std::visit(*this, var); }

    template <typename U>
    T operator()(U) { throw std::bad_variant_access(); }
};

template<typename T, typename Variant>
T Get(const Variant& var) {
    Getter<T> getter;
    return getter(var);
}

/* or 
template <typename T>
inline Getter<T> Get;
*/
```